# Creating a metaclass to unpack a struct into a namedtuple

Tags: python

I've recently read a few SO questions on metaclasses, and while it seems like something that's not necessary to use most of the time (including my question), I thought it'd be interesting for this case.

In the python docs for [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html?highlight=namedtuple#examples), there is an example with namedtuple here:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Student = namedtuple('Student', 'name serialnum school gradelevel')
Student._make(unpack('<10sHHb', record))
```

My question is: is it possible to create a metaclass that I could use to do part of this for me? Like my intended solution is:

```
class Student(object):
    __metaclass__ = ???
    fields = 'name serialnum school gradelevel'
    struct = '<10sHHb'

s = Student(record) # and give same output as the _make() call above
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, but if you like, you can use `self.__name__` to get the name of the class you're working with, so you can construct a `namedtuple` in your constructor, agnostic of the actual name you gave the class.

Comment: @2rs2ts I want to define a class just by giving its fields and the struct layout, so that it can be constructed from its data directly. So that the result of the 2nd block is the same as the 1st block.

Comment: Oh. I would use `setattr` for this. I'm not familiar with the `struct` module but I would say pass in the struct string and unpack it, then use `setattr` based on the results of the unpacking.

Comment: Related: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576666-nicer-struct-syntax-thanks-to-py3-metaclasses/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely an interesting problem, here is my solution:

```
import struct
import collections

class MetaStruct(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        nt = collections.namedtuple(clsname, dct['fields'])
        def new(cls, record):
            return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, *struct.unpack(dct['struct'], record))
        dct.update(__new__=new)
        return super(MetaStruct, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, (nt,), dct)

class Student(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaStruct
    fields = 'name serialnum school gradelevel'
    struct = '<10sHHb'

record = 'raymond   \x32\x12\x08\x01\x08'
s = Student(record)
```

The significant difference between my answer and the others is that at the end of this `Student` is still a class and `s` is an instance of `Student` (`isinstance(s, Student)` returns True).  I accomplished this by having the metaclass add the namedtuple as a base class of the newly created class, with object creation of the new class (`Student.__new__`) delegated to the base class (the namedtuple).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from struct import pack, unpack

class MetaStruct(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
        nt = namedtuple(name, attrs.pop('fields'))
        struct = attrs.pop('struct')
        def factory(record):
            return nt._make(unpack(struct, record))
        return factory

class Student(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaStruct
    fields = 'name serialnum school gradelevel'
    struct = '<10sHHb'

record = pack('<10sHHb', 'student123', 123, 456, 12)
s = Student(record)
# => Student(name='student123', serialnum=123, school=456, gradelevel=12)
```

The `MetaStruct` metaclass cheats a bit: it defines the specified `namedtuple`, but instead of an actual class (as metaclasses are expected to), it returns a factory function that produces instances of the `namedtuple`; still, the "class" defined using this metaclass is expected to return a `namedtuple` upon instantiation and not a fully-fledged class instance, so this is kind of inevitable. It could define an actual subclass with the defined `namedtuple` as a parent, but it seems overkill in your scenario.

Comment: This is pretty clever, but it does have the caveat that `Student` will not be a class, so something like `isinstance(s, Student)` will raise an exception.  This would be pretty confusing to diagnose, you are probably better of just creating a factory function instead of using the class/metaclass magic.

Comment: Was interested to see if I could work around the issue from my last comment, just added a similar answer that seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

lanzz's answer is pretty neat; here is an alternate method using decorators:

```
class Dec(object):
    def __init__(self, cls, fields=None, struct=None):
        print cls,fields,struct
        self.cls = cls
        self.nt = namedtuple(cls.__name__, fields or cls.fields)
        self.struct = struct

    def __call__(self, record):
        return self.nt._make(unpack(self.struct or self.cls.struct, record))


@Dec
class Student(object):
    fields = 'name serialnum school gradelevel'
    struct = '<10sHHb'


s = Student('abcdefghla00000')
```

It does the same thing as the metaclass but using a decorator class.  You could also use a decorator method, and you can modify either to take fields/struct as decorator arguments.  So many possibilities...

Is one method better than the other?  I'm not sure, it probably comes down to preference.  For this task I would probably prefer a decorator since you're not really creating classes but namedtuple factories, but that's just me.